# Performance Issue: rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineExecutionSService

Tags: elasticsearch

I've struggled to transfer 500 Million documents, which are shipped from Windows IIS logs, from kafka to elasticsearch. At the beginning of shipping process, Everything is good.

From Kafka-manager dashboard, I could see the speed of document out/bytes is about 1 million per minutes.

After one week, The speed of out/bytes is decreased to 200K per minutes. I thought that it has some problem. As I opened elasticsearch log file, I could see numerous of ERRORs.

Error is the below statement.

> [ERROR][o.e.a.b.TransportBulkAction] [***-node-2] failed to execute
>   pipeline for a bulk request org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineExecutionSService$..... on EsThreadPoolExecutor

At the first time, I thought it was a problem of thread pool deficiency..
But tuning write thread pool is not strongly recommended by elasticsearch forum.

At the second time, it came from ingest-geoip because error statement said that "ingest.PipelineExecution....", So i simplified geoip filter in my logstash configuration. that is, turn off geoip.

Also, Tried to reduce the number of pipeline worker, and the number of batch size in logstash config.

Everything'd failed... There is no hope for overcoming this error.

Help Genius!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log you pasted it looks like the queue capacity is 200, but there are 203 queued tasks. I guess that either the indexing is slow due to ingest pipelines taking too long, or that there is a burst of indexing data which puts pressure on the queue. another option is that you are not rolling over the index, and when an index is getting too big the merges are bigger and longer and indexing performance decreases.

I would start by increasing the queue capacity to 2000, monitor the queue size, and check whether you get momentary/long bursts of incoming data.
Another thing to do is to monitor the indexing latency, and check whether ingest pipelines are the bottleneck, by checking their timing. you can try disabling them for a short time (if that is acceptable) and see if that relaxes the queue and errors in the log.

Comment: I've used ingest-geoip plugin to mark country_code. I Also turned off it. but the lack of queue capacity problem isn't getting well. So, Now I'm trying to split index, which has only 5 shards and size is about 65 GB. I think that because of huge shard size, there might be slow indexing problem and writing data into shards...

Comment: I would check the analyze and tokenizers as well, in the template/mapping of the index. Maybe you are doing too much in indexing? The shards sizes sounds reasonable and not huge, if each shard is less than 20gb. Maybe you are writing in too high rate? Try to add more shards if that is the case

Comment: I'm not quite keen on shard reallocation. Could I increase the number of shard with keeping elasticsearch cluster alive. I Couldn't find the exact solution from internet. What is the keyword that match what I want to do.

Comment: You can't increase the amount of shards in an existing index. Also re-allocating of big shards might be resources intensive. What I meant is that you would create a new index, with more shards, and move the indexing to the new index. you can either use elasticsearch rollover API or do it yourself using 2 aliases on the indices - one alias for search (put it on all indices) and a second alias to write (put it only on the active writable index). then you can add indices and shards under the hood.

Comment: Thanks my approach was impossible. I appreciate your smart advise. I have to follow what you teach to me. Thanks alot!

Comment: also, take my advice and increase the queue capacity to 2000. this will give you better buffer for indexing bursts/hiccups. then you can monitor when the queue is growing and try to correlate with the root cause of the queue grow. this can help you pinpoint the bottleneck

Comment: also thanks a lot! your ideas is a single light in the darkness !